# If $F$ is the CDF of $X$, then $F(X)$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

1. Let $X$ be a random variable that has a Cumulative Distribution Function $F(X)$.
2. Let $Y = F(X)$ be the random variable represented by the CDF itself.
3. I seek to prove that $Y \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,1)$.

#### Context

This can't be true for an arbitrary $X$: if $P(X=a)=1$ for some $a$, then $f(X)=f(a)$ with probability $1$, for any function $f$. An additional assumption is needed. Is the statement true under assumption that $X$ is a continuous random variable, i.e., $F$ is a continuous function?

Comment: I clarified the question and removed the conversational tone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us start with a proper statement.

If $X$ is a random variable with CDF $F$, then $F(X)\sim U[0,1]$.

For this, it is enough to prove that, for $0<y<1$:
$$
P(F(X) \le y)=y
$$because a random variable is characterized by its CDF.

Consider a decreasing sequence of continuous functions, strictly increasing,
such as $F_n \downarrow F$ pointwise. Then using the monotonic convergence theorem:
$$
P(F(X) \le y) = \lim P(F_n(X) \le y) \\
P(F_n(X) \le  y) = P(X \le  F_n^{-1}(y)) = F(F_n^{-1}(y))
$$
Eventually, using the right continuity of $F$, you get
$$
P(F(X)\le  y) =y
$$(the proof is significantly clearer when $F$ is strictly increasing).

Comment: The statement is only true for continuous $F$. If the distribution of $X$ has an atom, the distribution of $F(X)$ will have it too.